# Can't write to response in Application_Start

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my Application_Start method I'm doing some setup and logging to my database. I had an issue where my connectionstring was wrong, which is not a big deal but I'd like to validate the database is available during Application_Start() and report back to the user if it's down.

Since the httpResponse isn't yet available I can't write something to the browser.

What other practical options do I have?

Comment: Move your validation code to a method later in the process where the request and response are available

Comment: @Nkosi The exception occurs in my Application_Start method.

Comment: Although I don't condone globals, you could set a global variable which states whether the database setup was successful. Something like a public static bool etc... in a class somewhere, then access it in some admin-only accessible view...

Comment: You're probably better off writing this to the event log. No point in telling one of Google's spiders that your database is down.

Comment: @RupertMorrish I was hoping to just have a "Site is offline" message instead of showing them a stacktrace or anything. I'm also using Azure web app so there's no Event Log that I know of.

Comment: @user3953989 you acknowledge request/response are not available in startup. Do lazy initialization in first request. That way if error thrown on first request it can be flagged and a friendly response is returned to client

Comment: it might be overkill, but you could do something like @squill25, set a property in the global.asax and then write an action filter that looks for the a property and then returns your message if it's set.

Comment: if you wanted to get real fancy that action filter could redirect you to an offline page.

Comment: Why don't you use Application_Error(). You can access the http context over there

Comment: @Fran I believe this is the best solution.

Comment: `Application_Start` doesn't have current request/response, you need to use `Application_BeginRequest` or `Application_Error` to write responses (`Application_Error` best suited for error message response).

Comment: I'm going to try some of these suggestions and report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick implementation of my suggestion.

Modify global.asax to have a public variable

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static bool IsConfigured { get; set; }
```

Set IsConfigured = true as you leave Application_Start if everything is configured

Then add a ActionFilter like this

```
public class ConfiguredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (MvcApplication.IsConfigured) return;

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "Offline",
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
        };
    }
}
```

Create your Offline view in the Shared views folder

Register your new filter

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new ConfiguredAttribute());
    }
}
```